# Class specific data files in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm writing a matlab class which uses data from a .mat-file.
Is there any way I can place this data file inside the class directory structure and make it accessible only to my class?

I.e. I have a directory structure like this:

```
./MATLAB
  +myPackage
    @MyClass
      MyClass.m
```

where MyClass.m looks like

```
classdef MyClass
  methods
    function y = getValue(obj, x)
      load datafile.mat
      y = interp1(datax, datay, x);
    end
  end
end
```

This works great as long as `datafile.mat` is in my working directory, but I'd like to move it to `+myPackage/@MyClass/datafile.mat` instead (or better yet `+myPackage/datafile.mat`). How would I make my class(es) find it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you may put the data file in a ['private'](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/private-functions.html) subfolder inside your directory structure:

```
./MATLAB
  +myPackage
    private
     datafile.mat
    @MyClass
     MyClass.m
```

NB: This won't garantee that it is only accessible to your class, anyway it will be classified close to your class definition.

Then, you can find back data values like this in your method:

```
classdef MyClass
  methods
    function y = getValue(obj, x)

      % Find back datafile name          
      localPath = fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'));
      dataFilename = fullfile(localpath, '..', 'private', 'datafile.mat'); % '..' is to go up one folder, up to you to place th file somewhere else (e.g. under +MyPackage directly)

      % Read file
      data = load(dataFilename);
      datax = data.datax;
      datay = data.datay;

      y = interp1(datax, datay, x);
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT: Example with Resources class**

Here is an example with separate resource class to avoid loading file data each time `getValue` is called. I also added for the case you need to care if the file has been modified or not:

```
classdef Resources

    methods(Static)
        function [resource] = GetResource(name, careForUpdates)
        %[
            if (nargin < 2), careForUpdates = true; end
            if (nargin < 1), error('Not enough input arguments.'); end

            persistent cache;
            if (isempty(cache)), cache = containers.Map('UniformValues', false); end

            filename = Resources.GetFileName(name);
            lastModified = dir(filename);
            lastModified = datenum(lastModified.date);
            if (~cache.isKey(name) || ...
                (careForUpdates &&   (cache(name).LastModified < lastModified)))
                data.LastModified = lastModified;
                data.Value = load(filename);                        
                cache(name) = data;                        
            end
            resource = cache(name).Value;            
        %]
        end
    end

    methods(Static, Access=private)
        function [fname] = GetFileName(name)
        %[
            persistent cache;
            if (isempty(cache)), cache = containers.Map('UniformValues', false); end
            if (~cache.isKey(name))
                localpath = fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'));
                switch(name)
                    case 'titi', cache(name) = fullfile(localpath, 'titi.mat');
                    case 'toto', cache(name) = fullfile(localpath, 'toto.mat');
                    case 'tata', cache(name) = fullfile(localpath, 'tata.mat');
                    otherwise, error('Resource `%s` is unknown', name)
                end
            end
            fname = cache(name);                             
        %]
        end
    end

end
```

This can be used like this

```
data = Resources.Get('titi');
```

Or, if not interested by file updates:

```
careForFileUpdates = false;
data = Resources.Get('titi', careForFileUpdates);
```

Comment: I was afraid it'd be something like this... A bit inelegant, but then again, it's matlab. Thanks!

Comment: @thomasloven For speed optimization, an alternative can be to place file reading in a static method (of this class or a service one, for instance +mypackage\@Resources). Static method job being: `if (neverReadOrFileChanged), cache = readFile(); end; return cache.Value;`

Comment: @thomasloven I added in my answer an example with separate class for managing resources.